# Pointer to a structure retains certain properties while resetting others to zero (using map)

Tags: c++

I am using map to store key and the pointer to the node in linked list. 
After creating the map, then i use MyMap.find(key), to get the iterator to the required entry. Using MyItr->second I retrieve the pointer to the node. 
But when I access the value stored at that node, the value is set to zero.

MyMap is defined as

```
map<int,Node*> MyMap; //map the key to the node in the linked list
```

Structure is as follows:

```
struct Node{
Node* next;
Node* prev;
int value;
int key;
Node(Node* p, Node* n, int k, int val):prev(p),next(n),key(k),value(val){};
Node(int k, int val):prev(NULL),next(NULL),key(k),value(val){};
};
```

The function set is as follows:

```
void set(int key,int value)
{

    if(counter<cp)
    {
        if(counter==0)
        {
            Node node(0,0,key,value);
            MyMap.insert(pair <int,Node*> (key,&node));
            head=&node;
            node.next=&node;
            node.prev=&node;
            prev_node=&node;
        }
        else
        {
            Node node(prev_node,head,key,value);
            MyMap.insert(pair <int,Node*> (key,&node));
            tail=&node;
            //tail=&node;
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

This is my get(key) function used to return the value:

```
int get(int k)
{

        //Node* node;
        Myitrerator=MyMap.find(k);
        if(Myitrator==MyMap.end())
        {
            return -1; // return -1 if not found
        }
        else
        {
            Node* np1=Myitrator->second;
            return np1->value; // value to the corresponding key 
            // this always return 0 even if the address returned
            //by Myiterator matches in debugger 
        }

}
```

This is the main function:

```
int main() {
int n, capacity,i; // capacity of Cache 
cin >> n >> capacity;
LRUCache l(capacity); // LRU is class contaning functions and map
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    string command;
    cin >> command;
    if(command == "get") {
        int key;
        cin >> key;
        cout << l.get(key) << endl;
    }
    else if(command == "set") {
        int key, value;
        cin >> key >> value;
        l.set(key,value);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Set(key,value) function creates new node to the linked list and adds the pointer to that node in the map with the key.

I know the doubly linked list is not properly implemented but that is not of my concern as of now as the list is not traversed to get to the values.
Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a **[mcve]**

Comment: Even after the edit, it's not a [MCVE]. We still have no idea what `mp` is declared as, and for that matter, you've introduced more unknowns with the undefined `LRUCache` (which might be the class your `get` is defined on, and might define `mp`, but we have *no* idea). Reducing it to a minimal repro benefits us and you (because in the process of reducing your problem to a minimal repro, you get a lot of information that might help you find the problem on your own).

Comment: At the very least, please show the code behind `l.set(key,value)`,maybe it is not populating the `map` correctly. Also show the input values you are entering on the console.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have added the required information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `set()` function is storing pointers to `Node` variables that are instantiated in automatic memory on the stack.  The variables go out of scope when `set()` exits, destroying the `Node` objects and leaving the pointers in the `map` dangling, so they are invalid when `get()` tries to access them.  Your code has **undefined behavior**.

You need to change `set()` to allocate the `Node` objects in dynamic memory on the heap using the `new` operator instead.

```
void set(int key,int value)
{
    if(counter<cp)
    {
        if(counter==0)
        {
            Node *node = new Node(0,0,key,value); // <--
            MyMap.insert(std::make_pair(key,node));
            head=node;
            node->next=node;
            node->prev=node;
            prev_node=node;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *node = new Node(prev_node,head,key,value); // <--
            MyMap.insert(std::make_pair(key,node));
            tail=node;
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

At some point, you will have to iterate the `map` destroying the `Node` objects when you are done using them:

```
for(std::map<int,Node*>::iterator iter = MyMap.begin(); iter != MyMap.end(); ++iter) {
    delete iter->second;
}
```

If you are using C++11 or later, you might consider using `std:::unique_ptr` (or `std::shared_ptr` with `std::weak_ptr`, since you are creating a linked list) to let the compiler handle that destruction of Nodes for you when the `map` is destroyed:

```
std::map<int,std::unique_ptr<Node>> MyMap;

void set(int key,int value)
{
    if(counter<cp)
    {
        if(counter==0)
        {
            std::unique_ptr<Node> node(new Node(0,0,key,value)); // <--
            MyMap.insert(std::make_pair(key,std::move(node)));
            head=node.get();
            node->next=head;
            node->prev=head;
            prev_node=head;
        }
        else
        {
            std::unique_ptr<Node> node(new Node(prev_node,head,key,value)); // <--
            MyMap.insert(std::make_pair(key,std::move(node)));
            tail=node.get();
        }
        counter++;
    }
}

int get(int k)
{
    auto Myitrerator = MyMap.find(k);
    if (Myitrator == MyMap.end())
        return -1; // return -1 if not found

    return Myitrator->second->value; // value to the corresponding key 
}
```

Comment: I was always wondering why do we need "new" when we can do the allocation otherwise. Now I know , Thanks a lot. Got a lot to learn yet.